# Can't store array of objects into local storage (Angular 9)

Tags: json, angular, typescript, local-storage, angular9

I'm trying to store an array of json objects into local storage and I have no idea why it's not working. I've tried to use `localStorage.setItem('comparisons', JSON.stringify(setComparisons))` but nothing gets stored for some reason.

I know the array I'm storing has the information I'm trying to store because it's all there when I log the array in the console before storing it.

I've also stored similar objects (not arrays of said objects though) in localStorage and retrieved them without any problems. I don't know if it's because of this being an array nested with arrays of arrays or what, but I can't figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import * as jasmineData from '../../../../assets/data/jasmine.json';
import * as belleData from '../../../../assets/data/belle.json';
import * as trumpData from '../../../../assets/data/trump.json';
import * as katyPerryData from '../../../../assets/data/katyPerry.json';
import * as snoopDogData from '../../../../assets/data/snoopDog.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-header',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
})


export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 
 constructor(){}
 
 ngOnInit(){

    if(localStorage.getItem('comparisons')){

      console.log("localStorage 'comparisons', set to: " + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('comparisons')))

      let testOutput = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('comparisons')) 

      console.log(testOutput) //<<<<< outputs nothing

    }
    else{

      let setComparisons = []

      setComparisons['jasmine'] = jasmineData['default']
      setComparisons['belle'] = belleData['default']
      setComparisons['trump'] = trumpData['default']
      setComparisons['katyPerry'] = katyPerryData['default']
      setComparisons['snoopDog'] = snoopDogData['default']

      console.log(setComparisons) //<<<<<<<<<< this works
 
      localStorage.setItem('comparisons', JSON.stringify(setComparisons)) //<<<<<<<<<<<< this doesn't work

    }
 }
```

and here is an example of one of the json objects inside the array:

```
trumpData['default'] = 

{
  "word_count": 43336,
  "processed_language": "en",
  "personality": [
    {
      "trait_id": "big5_openness",
      "name": "Openness",
      "category": "personality",
      "percentile": 0.9635579519385504,
      "raw_score": 0.8059142660098279,
      "significant": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_adventurousness",
          "name": "Adventurousness",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.6272749945581317,
          "raw_score": 0.5163639722247335,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_artistic_interests",
          "name": "Artistic interests",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.5549904649909926,
          "raw_score": 0.672324948928981,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_emotionality",
          "name": "Emotionality",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.28058970637230307,
          "raw_score": 0.6245047073901818,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_imagination",
          "name": "Imagination",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.19081218603999944,
          "raw_score": 0.6914017394955871,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_intellect",
          "name": "Intellect",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.9812082240575732,
          "raw_score": 0.7034946040858857,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_liberalism",
          "name": "Authority-challenging",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.61502043736225,
          "raw_score": 0.5309578314898162,
          "significant": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "big5_conscientiousness",
      "name": "Conscientiousness",
      "category": "personality",
      "percentile": 0.983679161419448,
      "raw_score": 0.727697468159296,
      "significant": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_achievement_striving",
          "name": "Achievement striving",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.9037639682132805,
          "raw_score": 0.7574010167811566,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_cautiousness",
          "name": "Cautiousness",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.9577606864915309,
          "raw_score": 0.6013821376687818,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_dutifulness",
          "name": "Dutifulness",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.8973055247237618,
          "raw_score": 0.6899127477824422,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_orderliness",
          "name": "Orderliness",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.6418796567676541,
          "raw_score": 0.5060623294980398,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_self_discipline",
          "name": "Self-discipline",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.9263490077860836,
          "raw_score": 0.6396844920960025,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_self_efficacy",
          "name": "Self-efficacy",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.8527803075035358,
          "raw_score": 0.7899712120456678,
          "significant": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "big5_extraversion",
      "name": "Extraversion",
      "category": "personality",
      "percentile": 0.881805735940201,
      "raw_score": 0.6038432240030011,
      "significant": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_activity_level",
          "name": "Activity level",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.6792742431580725,
          "raw_score": 0.564207098178294,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_assertiveness",
          "name": "Assertiveness",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.9590138650026484,
          "raw_score": 0.7310095956169131,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_cheerfulness",
          "name": "Cheerfulness",
          "cttegory": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.22893261753027844,
          "raw_score": 0.5932251409353175,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_excitement_seeking",
          "name": "Excitement-seeking",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.07232250370319887,
          "raw_score": 0.5417548838864124,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_friendliness",
          "name": "Outgoing",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.6581074192508122,
          "raw_score": 0.5809171726499361,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_gregariousness",
          "name": "Gregariousness",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.20363538067938197,
          "raw_score": 0.4107392559079223,
          "significant": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "big5_agreeableness",
      "name": "Agreeableness",
      "category": "personality",
      "percentile": 0.636750368115894,
      "raw_score": 0.7561040242628326,
      "significant": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_altruism",
          "name": "Altruism",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.8106883789426762,
          "raw_score": 0.7359758754762658,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_cooperation",
          "name": "Cooperation",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.5694503320384123,
          "raw_score": 0.5899309252875584,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_modesty",
          "name": "Modesty",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.40713913944183266,
          "raw_score": 0.43598028092279484,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_morality",
          "name": "Uncompromising",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.8195717940201414,
          "raw_score": 0.6689246296236344,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_sympathy",
          "name": "Sympathy",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.9920577260424773,
          "raw_score": 0.755562118052558,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_trust",
          "name": "Trust",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.47298674696745124,
          "raw_score": 0.5830101087027785,
          "significant": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "big5_neuroticism",
      "name": "Emotional range",
      "category": "personality",
      "percentile": 0.13904938204251915,
      "raw_score": 0.4595539073395768,
      "significant": true,
      "children": [
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_anger",
          "name": "Fiery",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.14592765984036238,
          "raw_score": 0.47807350135271154,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_anxiety",
          "name": "Prone to worry",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.08697282793529115,
          "raw_score": 0.5013887984737312,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_depression",
          "name": "Melancholy",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.16680824488529322,
          "raw_score": 0.3872001388285126,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_immoderation",
          "name": "Immoderation",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.05246097936296118,
          "raw_score": 0.4382727933313163,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_self_consciousness",
          "name": "Self-consciousness",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.07969774599416085,
          "raw_score": 0.47267337369288276,
          "significant": true
        },
        {
          "trait_id": "facet_vulnerability",
          "name": "Susceptible to stress",
          "category": "personality",
          "percentile": 0.0273807153901362,
          "raw_score": 0.3452475153303576,
          "significant": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "needs": [
    {
      "trait_id": "need_challenge",
      "name": "Challenge",
      "category": "needs",
      "percentile": 0.08110205321079733,
      "raw_score": 0.669099706309445,
      "significant": true
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "need_closeness",
      "name": "Closeness",
      "category": "needs",
      "percentile": 0.09291402531402237,
      "raw_score": 0.7346366531130437,
      "significant": true
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "need_curiosity",
      "name": "Curiosity",
      "category": "needs",
      "percentile": 0.2183155687091271,
      "raw_score": 0.7961768121584263,
      "significant": true
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "need_excitement",
      "name": "Excitement",
      "category": "needs",
      "percentile": 0.02286176344029084,
      "raw_score": 0.5264979907029215,
      "significant": true
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "need_harmony",
      "name": "Harmony",
      "category": "needs",
      "percentile": 0.03427014251932459,
      "raw_score": 0.7463631682958176,
      "significant": true
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "need_ideal",
      "name": "Ideal",
      "category": "needs",
      "percentile": 0.05741159343084268,
      "raw_score": 0.6161180176812197,
      "significant": true
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "need_liberty",
      "name": "Liberty",
      "category": "needs",
      "percentile": 0.02216408649103313,
      "raw_score": 0.6611766254368321,
      "significant": true
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "need_love",
      "name": "Love",
      "category": "needs",
      "percentile": 0.015052473849888615,
      "raw_score": 0.6631615559158821,
      "significant": true
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "need_practicality",
      "name": "Practicality",
      "category": "needs",
      "percentile": 0.08611576821290123,
      "raw_score": 0.6982802364811073,
      "significant": true
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "need_self_expression",
      "name": "Self-expression",
      "category": "needs",
      "percentile": 0.07504383162546596,
      "raw_score": 0.6253916730109863,
      "significant": true
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "need_stability",
      "name": "Stability",
      "category": "needs",
      "percentile": 0.41330474153377117,
      "raw_score": 0.727472877321253,
      "significant": true
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "need_structure",
      "name": "Structure",
      "category": "needs",
      "percentile": 0.5785073814374321,
      "raw_score": 0.7014458089713079,
      "significant": true
    }
  ],
  "values": [
    {
      "trait_id": "value_conservation",
      "name": "Conservation",
      "category": "values",
      "percentile": 0.16678415814865472,
      "raw_score": 0.6218884680694995,
      "significant": true
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "value_openness_to_change",
      "name": "Openness to change",
      "category": "values",
      "percentile": 0.08647094085994467,
      "raw_score": 0.7317164337859383,
      "significant": true
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "value_hedonism",
      "name": "Hedonism",
      "category": "values",
      "percentile": 0.047762743756957216,
      "raw_score": 0.6316746177041674,
      "significant": true
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "value_self_enhancement",
      "name": "Self-enhancement",
      "category": "values",
      "percentile": 0.00590828237726021,
      "raw_score": 0.5958789067897858,
      "significant": true
    },
    {
      "trait_id": "value_self_transcendence",
      "name": "Self-transcendence",
      "category": "values",
      "percentile": 0.05270413599836593,
      "raw_score": 0.8065859855129559,
      "significant": true
    }
  ],
  "consumption_preferences": [
    {
      "consumption_preference_category_id": "consumption_preferences_shopping",
      "name": "Purchasing Preferences",
      "consumption_preferences": [
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_automobile_ownership_cost",
          "name": "Likely to be sensitive to ownership cost when buying automobiles",
          "score": 1.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_automobile_safety",
          "name": "Likely to prefer safety when buying automobiles",
          "score": 1.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_clothes_quality",
          "name": "Likely to prefer quality when buying clothes",
          "score": 1.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_clothes_style",
          "name": "Likely to prefer style when buying clothes",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_clothes_comfort",
          "name": "Likely to prefer comfort when buying clothes",
          "score": 1.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_influence_brand_name",
          "name": "Likely to be influenced by brand name when making product purchases",
          "score": 0.5
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_influence_utility",
          "name": "Likely to be influenced by product utility when making product purchases",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_influence_online_ads",
          "name": "Likely to be influenced by online ads when making product purchases",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_influence_social_media",
          "name": "Likely to be influenced by social media when making product purchases",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_influence_family_members",
          "name": "Likely to be influenced by family when making product purchases",
          "score": 1.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_spur_of_moment",
          "name": "Likely to indulge in spur of the moment purchases",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_credit_card_payment",
          "name": "Likely to prefer using credit cards for shopping",
          "score": 1.0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "consumption_preference_category_id": "consumption_preferences_health_and_activity",
      "name": "Health & Activity Preferences",
      "consumption_preferences": [
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_eat_out",
          "name": "Likely to eat out frequently",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_gym_membership",
          "name": "Likely to have a gym membership",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_outdoor",
          "name": "Likely to like outdoor activities",
          "score": 1.0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "consumption_preference_category_id": "consumption_preferences_environmental_concern",
      "name": "Environmental Concern Preferences",
      "consumption_preferences": [
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_concerned_environment",
          "name": "Likely to be concerned about the environment",
          "score": 1.0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "consumption_preference_category_id": "consumption_preferences_entrepreneurship",
      "name": "Entrepreneurship Preferences",
      "consumption_preferences": [
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_start_business",
          "name": "Likely to consider starting a business in next few years",
          "score": 0.5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "consumption_preference_category_id": "consumption_preferences_movie",
      "name": "Movie Preferences",
      "consumption_preferences": [
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_movie_romance",
          "name": "Likely to like romance movies",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_movie_adventure",
          "name": "Likely to like adventure movies",
          "score": 1.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_movie_horror",
          "name": "Likely to like horror movies",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_movie_musical",
          "name": "Likely to like musical movies",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_movie_historical",
          "name": "Likely to like historical movies",
          "score": 1.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_movie_science_fiction",
          "name": "Likely to like science-fiction movies",
          "score": 1.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_movie_war",
          "name": "Likely to like war movies",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_movie_drama",
          "name": "Likely to like drama movies",
          "score": 1.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_movie_action",
          "name": "Likely to like action movies",
          "score": 1.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_movie_documentary",
          "name": "Likely to like documentary movies",
          "score": 1.0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "consumption_preference_category_id": "consumption_preferences_music",
      "name": "Music Preferences",
      "consumption_preferences": [
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_music_rap",
          "name": "Likely to like rap music",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_music_country",
          "name": "Likely to like country music",
          "score": 0.5
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_music_r_b",
          "name": "Likely to like R&B music",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_music_hip_hop",
          "name": "Likely to like hip hop music",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_music_live_event",
          "name": "Likely to attend live musical events",
          "score": 1.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_music_playing",
          "name": "Likely to have experience playing music",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_music_latin",
          "name": "Likely to like Latin music",
          "score": 1.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_music_rock",
          "name": "Likely to like rock music",
          "score": 0.5
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_music_classical",
          "name": "Likely to like classical music",
          "score": 1.0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "consumption_preference_category_id": "consumption_preferences_reading",
      "name": "Reading Preferences",
      "consumption_preferences": [
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_read_frequency",
          "name": "Likely to read often",
          "score": 1.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_books_entertainment_magazines",
          "name": "Likely to read entertainment magazines",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_books_non_fiction",
          "name": "Likely to read non-fiction books",
          "score": 1.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_books_financial_investing",
          "name": "Likely to read financial investment books",
          "score": 0.0
        },
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_books_autobiographies",
          "name": "Likely to read autobiographical books",
          "score": 1.0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "consumption_preference_category_id": "consumption_preferences_volunteering",
      "name": "Volunteering Preferences",
      "consumption_preferences": [
        {
          "consumption_preference_id": "consumption_preferences_volunteer",
          "name": "Likely to volunteer for social causes",
          "score": 1.0
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "warnings": [
    {
      "warning_id": "CONTENT_TRUNCATED",
      "message": "For maximum accuracy while also optimizing processing time, only the first 250KB of input text (excluding markup) was analyzed. Accuracy levels off at approximately 3,000 words so this did not affect the accuracy of the profile."
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you check the total size of the array?

Comment: is there a limit to the size you can store in localStorage? If so, what is it?

Comment: Check length. You have limit 10mb

Comment: It should be about 115KB

Comment: Is that per object stored or total? Is there a limit for the size of each object?

Comment: [Max Local Stroage Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values)

Comment: Its definitely not the size, 115KB is way below the limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing an array, but then using string keys to set the data. So either use an actual object:

```
const setComparisons = {
  jasmine: jasmineData['default'],
  // etc
};
```

or use an array with numeric indices:

```
const setComparisons = [
  jasmineData['default'],
  // etc
];
```

You can leave your `setData` and `getData` as is.

The reason it doesn't work your way, is because the native `toJSON` method on array only takes items in the array into account, not any other property that might be present on the object. This method is called when an object is being stringified

Comment: FOSHO! Thanks Poul that did the trick. Appreciate your help!